# Code present while editing is not part of question now

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12835726. This question had code which I edited, but when I see the suggested edit, this code is not a part of original question. Thus it is getting rejected by reviewers as

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer

Comment: OP removed the code while you were editing, thus now it looks like you introduced the code..

Comment: Your edit has now been approved, but the question is still beyond salvaging. You're better off improving posts which do add any value to the site.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for the approval, yes i will keep it in mind in future, but for me surprise is "how the code got deleted, and it didn't got caught as subsequent edit", might be the timing as i guess :)

Comment: BTW the first person personal pronoun is "I" (capitalized), not "i". This is one more thing that should be fixed in edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Floern points out in the comments, the OP and you edited the question at the same time.

The question was only a minute old at the time, and the OP had not submitted any edits yet. So the OP's edit was within the 5 minute grace period, and does not show up in the edit history.

So what the reviewers saw was the OP's changed post, next to your edit of the original post. Which, unfortunately, made it look like you added the code.

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect answer to my doubts :)